# schedule job for given time

Tags: java, timer

I have task which should be done reapited daily for given time.

I have one scheduler  which scedule that task .but for e.g when I Started the scheduler at 2 pm then for next day schedule it 2 pm ,if started at 3 pm then schedule's it to next day for 3 pm.

But I want whenever schedule start but that task should be execute at given time.
I am passing  only the time in millisecond.

Is any way to pass the time in millisecond and that scheduler execute at given time only

reply if any one knows.

Comment: Why have formatted your question as code? It makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always [`Quartz Scheduler`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html) to do this , Have a look at its [`quick start guide`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html) , [*here*](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/) is quick example

Answer (score 1):

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple solution or don't want to use a framework, take a look at [java.util.Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29):

> Fixed-rate execution is appropriate for recurring activities that are sensitive to absolute time, such as ringing a chime every hour on the hour, or running scheduled maintenance every day at a particular time. It is also appropriate for recurring activities where the total time to perform a fixed number of executions is important, such as a countdown timer that ticks once every second for ten seconds. Finally, fixed-rate execution is appropriate for scheduling multiple repeating timer tasks that must remain synchronized with respect to one another.